# Linux Pytorch.cuda.is_available() returns false

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, pytorch

I tried to use pytorch 1.4.0 with GPU but `cuda.is_available` returned `false`.
I installed pytorch using conda:

```
conda install pytorch==1.4.0 torchvision==0.5.0 cudatoolkit=10.1
```

this is the output of `cat /proc/version`:

```
Linux version 5.8.0-40-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-014) (gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #45~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP
```

and this is the output of `nvidia-smi`:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.32.03    Driver Version: 460.32.03    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 3080    Off  | 00000000:65:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 33%   27C    P8     4W / 320W |     47MiB / 10010MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1134      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 36MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1297      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                9MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and the output of `conda list`(part of it):

```
Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
cudatoolkit               10.1.243             h6bb024c_0   
ninja                     1.10.2           py38hff7bd54_0  
python                    3.8.2               hcff3b4d_14  
pytorch                   1.4.0           py3.8_cuda10.1.243_cudnn7.6.3_0    https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/pytorch 
torchvision               0.5.0                py38_cu101    https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/pytorch
yacs                      0.1.6                      py_0    conda-forge
yaml                      0.2.5                h7b6447c_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3  
zstd                      1.4.5                h9ceee32_0
```

As far as I know my Linux server could support pytorch 1.4.0 but it didn't. what should I do?

Comment: nvidia-smi doesn't say anything about what cuda versions are installed, only what the maximum support level of the driver is

Comment: The pytorch 1.4.0 binaries available via pip or conda probably aren't built with support for compute capability 8.6 (used by GTX 3080) since it wasn't released at the time.

Comment: Also the oldest CUDA version that is supported by the 3080 is CUDA 11.0 so even if the binaries were somehow compiled with sm_86 support this wouldn't work since you installed pytorch for cuda 10.1.